# Bookshelf запросы к БД

Tags: javascript, postgresql, reactjs, vue.js

Добрый день.

Есть таблица Questions в которой хранятся вопросы и в ней же есть столбец author_question - в котором хранится id пользователя.

Есть таблица Users в которой хранятся пользователи и там есть столбец username, который содержит имя пользователя.

При запросе к БД мне нужно получить список с вопросами и я его успешно получаю. Но в этом списке присутствует id пользователя и это логично т.к. в таблице Questions в столбце author_question хранится именно id.

Вопрос: Как мне в одном запросе по этому id **при получении списка вопросов** сразу получить и имя пользователя из таблици Users.

Что делаю:
Файл model.js

```
import bookshelf from './bookshelf';

export const Users = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users'
});

export const Questions = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'questions',
  author_question: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Users, 'username');
  }
});
```

Файл(роут) с самим запросом:

```
getQuestions.post('/', (req, res) => {      
  Questions.query(function(db) {        
  }).fetchAll({ withRelated:['author_question'] })
  .then(questions => {    
    if (questions) {            
      res.json({ questions });
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ errors: { form: 'Invalid Credentials' } 
    });
  }
 });
});
```

В итоге получаю ошибку :
Unhandled rejection Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select "users".* from "users" where "users"."id" in (?)

Я по ходу где-то с самим синтаксисом напортачил и не понял принцип построения связей в bookshelf. Разъясните с указанием на ошибки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю стоит начать с того что бы поменять описание связи и имя поля на такое которое ожидает bookshelf. 
Обычно связанные поля называют как: имясвязаннойтаблицы_id
т.е в описанном случае в табличке questions поле должно называться user_id или author_id что чуть более выразительно. 
С такими именами другим программистам будет проще ориентироваться в структуре таблиц, так как по имени поля сразу будет видно суть связи.

Затем описать саму связь:

```js
export const Questions = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'questions',
  author: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Users); 
  }
});
```

Обратите внимание что вторым аргументом к belongsTo я ничего не передаю. 
Обычно вторым аргументом передается название поля через которое определяется связь, 
В коде было указано 'username', т.е bookshelf скорее всего искал поле с именем username в таблице questions. Его там не было соответственно связь не была оперделена.
Если же ничего не передать то bookshelf решит что в таблице должно быть поле с именем "названиесвязи_id", Т.е author_id.
Если же есть желание оставить имена полей или нет возможности менять их названия то можно описать связь так:

```js
export const Questions = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'questions',
  author_question: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Users, 'author_question'); 
  }
});
```

Но такое именование выглядит излишним. Поле author_question уже и так находится в таблице questions, т.е нет никакого смысла использовать слово "question" и в имени поля и в имени таблицы. Использование компактных имен более удобно, так как часто приходится писать запросы без использования ORM, а напрямую в клиенте базы данных.